# Import other peoples calendar from Outlook

Tags: ms-office, ical, exchange

I don't think this is possible but still not sure, maybe it is:

Can I import other people's calendar into iCal?  Those calendars are Microsoft Outlook Exchange Calendars.

Answer (score 1):

ha! Actually it is possible
Here we go: http://www.it.cornell.edu/services/ical/howto/view-shared.cfm

Comment: well , you answered it yourself.